# I used Shape Builder tool to create this but then I got more anchor points, So how to remove excess anchor points from the art?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, anchor-point

I was creating a logo for an organization and then when I used Shape Builder tool to create a shape from a circle.It turned out to have more anchor points that that kind of shape should probably have how to remove that excess anchor points and simplify that shape ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Smooth tool. It could help you to get rid of most of the unwanted anchor points
The Smooth Tool lets you go back and slightly modify a selected Path by drawing over it.

here's the demonstration:-
[image]